# Logging facilities and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, logging

What logging facilities do you use whit Qt ?

Do you choose qDebug(), qWarning(), qCritical(), qFatal() methods, or maybe something like Log4cpp (Log4cplus etc.), or maybe some custom-maked code ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existing C++ logging libraries are too heavy for my tastes, so I have created a custom front-end based on ideas from [Logging in C++](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/201804215) for the Qt qInstallMsgHandlerq back-end. It's cross-platform and thread-safe. Someday I'll clean up the code and release it to the world :)

An interesting alternative for Qt is [QxtLogger](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtlogger.html).

Comment: Maybe QxtLogger is best solution for Qt based projects. Only drawback (at my opinion), that this logger is part of pretty big library. Anyway, thanks for your advise.

Comment: @vnm: I have published my logging library at http://bitbucket.org/razvanpetru/qt-components/downloads/

Comment: Just to update - there is now an official http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Advanced,_cross-platform_logging_for_Qt

Comment: Pity all the links are now broken, I was hoping to take a look.

Comment: How does this text qualify as an answer ***"Existing C++ logging libraries are too heavy for my tastes, so I have created a custom front-end based on ideas from Logging in C++ for the Qt qInstallMsgHandlerq back-end. It's cross-platform and thread-safe. Someday I'll clean up the code and release it to the world :)"***.. What *"existing C++ logging libraries"* are you referring to? And why are they "too heavy"? Also, how does your custom library solve the problem? Any benchmark? And most importantly, how does it solve readers' problem if it is not available for use?

Answer (score 12):

If you are just working in a single thread, qDebug and such work pretty well, or you can modify them somewhat by installing your own handler with qInstallMessageHandler in QT 5.0+, or qInstallMsgHandler in old versions.

Note: Older versions of qDebug() etc., where you used qInstallMsgHandler (now deprecated, e.g. http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtglobal.html#qDebug) were not thread-safe. If you use threads, they would crash/break badly.  Internally it was using QTextStream, which was reentrant, but not thread-safe.

Comment: -1 `qDebug()` is thread-safe. The thread-safety of `QTextStream` is irrelevant because there is no shared `QTextStream`. Each invokation of `qDebug()` gets its own `QTextStream`.

Comment: @Oktalist: I don't agree with you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23517726/1202500 - and the answer(s) there is / are exactly my experience...

Comment: @mozzbozz Thanks. If `qDebug` is unsafe then it is not for the reason given by DarrylC. If you install your own thread-safe `QtMessageHandler` then `qDebug` will be thread-safe. The default handler may interleave output but I don't believe there is a data race/UB, although I can't prove it.

Comment: @Oktalist Surprised you know that so certainly, since not many people have access to the Meego devices and source that showed it back in the late 2010/early 2011.  That was the failure back then (and also on Symbian, if I remember correctly).  What happens now I don't know, but you still shouldn't rely upon something being thread-safe that is not documented as being thread-safe, if you want the software used for more than a throw-away prototype.  That is how you get code-rot: relying upon accidental behavior of today's implementation, rather than upon the specification.

Comment: I start supporting the claim that "qDebug() is not thread-safe". My experience has shown that in a multi-threaded application, the use of qDebug() may sometimes lead to crash or freeze. The problem is that this is hard to reproduce. A simple code example that can consistently reproduce the crash/freeze would help to confirm this claim.

Comment: @jonathanzh Compiling Qt with [`-fsanitize=thread`](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual) would help to confirm.

Comment: qDebug and friends are now documented to be thread-safe (and they've  always been thread-safe at least in Qt 4, 5 times): https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qDebug

Answer (score 11):

Since Qt 5.2 supports categorized logging: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html . This allows you to split up your logging messages into a (hierarchy of) categories, and fine tune which is logged, and what not.

Answer (score 7):

[Log4Qt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4qt/) is a port of famous log4j to the Qt world.

Answer (score 4):

QDebug is the best way to go, as it presents out-of-the-box integration with the rest of the framework, doesn't make you dependent on 3rd party code and covers pretty all of the logging needs.

Comment: But it does not log to files or the system event log.

Comment: It doesn't do that by default, but that's not a good default as for me. If you want to reroute qDebug, refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954140/how-to-redirect-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-etc-output

Comment: I know that you can re-route qDebug. Still its not flexible enough for a mature application.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using Qt, but for logging I'm using a modified version of Dr'Dobb's [Logging in C++](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/201804215). The original code can be found [here](ftp://66.77.27.238/sourcecode/ddj/2007/0710.zip).

My modifications are specific to the Microsoft Windows platform (fopen doesn't allow file read sharing) and can be found [here](http://code.assembla.com/cristianadam/subversion/nodes/Log).

Comment: In Qt several classes have a quite comfortable human readable serialization facilities, which should ihmo be called by a good Qt-logging library implicitely. A general C++ logging framework is here not good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the answer saying "Unfortunately qDebug() etc. are not thread-safe. If you use threads, they will crash/break badly. Internally it uses QTextStream, which is reentrant, but not thread-safe."

I seriously doubt that, qDebug is designed to be used concurrently. File a bug if that isn't true.

Comment: The source seems to be http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28879-redirecting-qDebug-to-file-threading-question

Comment: Doubt it or not - it doesn't matter.  In 2011, on at least 1 platform, using it from multiple threads did crash.  If it isn't documented as thread-safe, then it should be assumed to not be thread-safe, because the implementation is subject to change - which means that it isn't a bug if it doesn't work.  If you want to ensure that the implementation doesn't change, then you need to copy the functionality, which means you are effectively writing your own version anyway (just with a head start).  If the doc's say it is thread-safe as of a particular version, then you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to use that log data.

If it is used for debugging at runtime, qWarning() would do just fine.

If you need to debug retrospective (usually server side code), plain old text files are the best. It is best to organize these log files by day log is written.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at: https://github.com/netresultsit/uniqlogger

- LGPL
- thread-safe
- multiple backends: file, colored console, network, rsyslog
- file rotation by size and number of files
- support compression of previous files
  etc.