# Avoid newline in qDebug()

Tags: c++, qt, newline, qdebug

Sometimes I want to output a single line in `qDebug()`, but with some conditional text, like

```
if (fontMetricsLeading < 0)
    qDebug() << "!!!";
qDebug() << fontMetricsLeading;
```

However, that would output them on 2 separate lines.

Is there a way to avoid appending a new line after each `qDebug()`?

Comment: I later found a related question (but it asks about spaces as well) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209823/how-to-call-qdebug-without-the-appended-spaces-and-newline

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I just found a solution that seems to work. Reading the docs qDebug() returns a temporary QDebug object, which appends newline on destruction. It seems this temporary object can be stored in a temporary variable:

```
QDebug debug = qDebug();
if (fontMetricsLeading < 0)
    debug << "!!!";
debug << fontMetricsLeading;
```

Comment: Things are more complicated (unnecessary complicated I might add) in Qt 5.7 (and probably in any 5.x). `qDebug()` no longer turns a ready-to-use `QDebug` object hence one has to tackle the whole thing by reading tons of documentation. Quite annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator.

```
qDebug() << (fontMetricsLeading < 0 ? "!!!" : "") << fontMetricsLeading;
```

An alternative would be to build a queue in a `QString` like this.

```
QString debugString;

if(fontMetricsLeading < 0)
    debugString += "!!!";

debugString += QString::number(fontMetricsLeading);

qDebug() << debugString;
```

Although I don't see why you would need to go to this extent if it's just for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of dealing with your situation.

```
QString msg;

if ( fontMetricsLeading < 0 )
{
    msg = "!!!";
}

qDebug( "%s, %d", qPrintable( msg ), fontMetricsLeading );
```