# Why are there double quotes when we print using QString?

Tags: qt

I am using Qt framework in Linux and a complete beginner.

When I print a simple message like:

```
qDebug() << "Hello World";
```

In the Console the output is `Hello World`.

But if I print the same message like:

```
QString str = "Hello World";
qDebug() << str;
```

In the Console the output is `"Hello World"`,**(Notice the quotes)**, How to get the same output using `QString`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976581/why-is-qstring-printed-with-quotation-marks

Comment: This is the way QString is implemented. If you want to remove the "", consider using a std::string, or potentially use a QByteArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [QDebug::noquote](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#noquote)

> Disables automatic insertion of quotation characters around QChar, QString and QByteArray contents and returns a reference to the stream.
>
> When quoting is disabled, these types are printed without quotation characters and without escaping of non-printable characters.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 5.4.

Usage:

```
QString str = "Hello World";
qDebug().noquote() << str;
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#noquote

Answer (score 1):

you can find the answer in the Qt source code(detail of implementation in the link below) :
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qdebug.h.html

you have several definitions of the << operator

from Qt source code :

> /*! \fn QDebug &QDebug::operator<<(const char *s)
>
> Writes the
>   '\0'-terminated string s, to the stream and returns a reference
>   to the stream. The string is never quoted nor transformed to the
>   output, but note that some QDebug backends might not be 8-bit clean.
>
> */ /*! \fn QDebug &QDebug::operator<<(const QString &s)
>
> Writes the string, \a s, to the stream and returns a reference to the stream.
>   Normally, QDebug prints the string inside quotes and transforms
>   non-printable characters to their Unicode values (\u1234). To print
>   non-printable characters without transformation, enable the noquote()
>   functionality. Note that some QDebug backends might not be 8-bit
>   clean. Output examples: \code QString s; s = "a"; qDebug().noquote()
>   << s; // prints: a qDebug() << s; // prints: "a" s = "\"a\r\n\"";
>   qDebug() << s; // prints: "\"a\r\n\"" s = "\033"; // escape character
>   qDebug() << s; // prints: "\u001B" s = "\u00AD"; // SOFT HYPHEN
>   qDebug() << s; // prints: "\u00AD" s = "\u00E1"; // LATIN SMALL LETTER
>   A WITH ACUTE qDebug() << s; // prints: "Ã¡" s = "a\u0301"; // "a"
>   followed by COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT qDebug() << s; // prints: "aÌ"; s =
>   "\u0430\u0301"; // CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A followed by COMBINING ACUTE
>   ACCENT qDebug() << s; // prints: "Ð°Ì" \endcode
>   */

qDebug()<< "hello world" uses QDebug &QDebug::operator<<(const char *s) and not QDebug &QDebug::operator<<(const QString &s) that's why you get the quotes in one version and not the other.
you can get the same result by using :

```
 qDebug().noquote() << s;
```

on the `QString` version

Comment: The code you've posted is not source code of Qt, it is from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#operator-lt-lt-13). The answer should contain a link (and an explanation of the options) rather than the comments in the source code of Qt.

Comment: You forgot to add the solution, you only showed the explanation.

Comment: the solution is at the end!  qDebug().noquote() << s;