# Qt: QGLShaderProgram turn off log messages

Tags: qt, opengl, shader

Is there a way to turn of log messages when calling QGLShaderProgram::link()?
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglshaderprogram.html#link

Messages look like:

```
QGLShader::link: "Vertex shader(s) linked, fragment shader(s) linked.
"
```

Qt code looks like this:
src/opengl/qglshaderprogram.cpp:893

```
    glLinkProgram(program);
    value = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &value);
    d->linked = (value != 0);
    value = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &value);
    d->log = QString();
    if (value > 1) {
        char *logbuf = new char [value];
        GLint len;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, value, &len, logbuf);
        d->log = QString::fromLatin1(logbuf);
        QString name = objectName();
        if (name.isEmpty())
            qWarning() << "QGLShader::link:" << d->log;
        else
            qWarning() << "QGLShader::link[" << name << "]:" << d->log;
        delete [] logbuf;
    }
    return d->linked;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the only possible solution is to redirect qWarning() as done in: [How to redirect qDebug, qWarning, qCritical etc output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954140/how-to-redirect-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-etc-output)

```
 qInstallMsgHandler([](QtMsgType , const char* ) { });  // empty message handler
 bool result = program.link();
 qInstallMsgHandler(0);  // restore default message handling
```