# C++ QT QFileDialog does not close when using system() in triggered action

Tags: c++, qt, system, qfiledialog

```
void OBJ_Loader::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open a File"));
if (!filename.isEmpty()) {
    filepath=filename.toUtf8().constData();

    command.append(filepath);
    int TempNumOne=command.size();
    for (int a=0;a<=TempNumOne;a++) { //get letters to a char list so it can be used by system();
                cmd[a]=command[a];
    }
    openfile=true;

    if (openfile) {
        openfile=false;
        system(cmd);
    }
}

}
```

When the system(cmd); is called the QFileDialog window does not close till the system command finishes. I would like to know if I can close the search window after clicking open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system` function blocks the event loop: the user interaction requires the event loop to run, and it runs when your code isn't running. Since the `system` invocation is in your code, you can't simply have it block your process. You need to use `QProcess` as it has an asynchronous interface. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602568/1329652) provides a complete example of one process calling itself -- all done from a single executable.