# QSystemSemaphore::acquire() abort

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, semaphore

I use QSharedMemory and QSystemSemaphore to organize event exchange between several processes. QSharedMemory stores number of receivers and event data. Receivers are awaiting in QSystemSemaphore::acquire(). Sender notifies them via QSystemSemaphore::release([number of receivers]).

Are there any way to terminate receiver process gracefully except introducing flag "real"/"fake" in shared memory and subsequent generating "fake" event in terminating process?

Comment: you quesiton is unclear formulated. You mean when you call `terminate` on the thread the thread does not teminate and is stuck in `QSystemSemaphore::acquire()` ?

Comment: This is an XY problem: you must let us see the forest, not the individual trees. What exactly are you doing? Most likely there's a much simpler solution to your problem - whatever that problem really is. Please edit the question to clarify the structure of your system, perhaps creating a short test case. You can [easily launch multiple processes from one `main.cpp`!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18602568/1329652).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QThread::terminate()` works on every platform, no matter what the thread is doing at the moment. Of course, when you have terminated **any** thread in an application, the only other thing you can safely do is call `abort`: the process is generally in a broken state at that point. **Do not** do anything other than `abort()`-ing after you call `QThread::terminate`. Since it's so destructive, you might as well forego calling `terminate` and abort directly.

Your question is phrased as if you had plans to continue on with the application after calling `terminate`. You must not!

Alas, if all you want is for a thread to quit, with the semaphore being a synchronization primitive, you can do so easily by setting a flag and releasing the semaphore. The below is a somewhat contrived example, as you wouldn't normally use a thread pool that way: it's only to make the code shorter.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/semaphore-quit-40488523
#include <QtCore>

class Worker : public QRunnable {
    static const QString m_key;
    static QAtomicInteger<bool> m_abort;
    void run() override {
        QSystemSemaphore sem{m_key};
        qDebug() << "working";
        while (true) {
            sem.acquire();
            if (m_abort.load()) {
                sem.release();
                qDebug() << "aborting";
                return;
            }
            sem.release();
        }
    }
public:
    static void acquire(int n = 1) {
        QSystemSemaphore sem{m_key};
        while (n--)
            sem.acquire();
    }
    static void release(int n = 1) {
        QSystemSemaphore{m_key}.release(n);
    }
    static void quit(int n) {
        m_abort.store(true);
        release(n);
    }
};
const QString Worker::m_key = QStringLiteral("semaphore-quit-40488523");
QAtomicInteger<bool> Worker::m_abort = false;

int main()
{
    QThreadPool pool;
    QVarLengthArray<Worker, 20> workers{20};
    for (auto & worker : workers) {
        worker.setAutoDelete(false);
        pool.start(&worker);
    }
    Worker::release(workers.size()); // get some workers churning
    QThread::sleep(5);
    Worker::acquire(workers.size()); // pause all the workers
    Worker::quit(workers.size());
    // The thread pool destructor will wait for all workers to quit.
}
```

Comment: OK, I mean that QThread::wait() after QThread::terminate() works (successfully completed) on Windows but not Linux. And I agree that terminate() is bad way, but what are the alternatives? The question is not about terminate(). It is about how to interrupt acquire().

Comment: @groaner Again, the **only** thing you can do after `QThread::terminate` is `abort()`. That it works on Windows is a coincidence. It doesn't have to work, and it's not guaranteed to work, and sure enough on Linux it doesn't work. The alternative is to `release` the semaphore... it's your semaphore, right? You must be doing something weird to it. Show your code.

Comment: It is not my (inprocess) semaphore. It is global (interprocess) semaphore (QSystemSemaphore, not QSemaphore). I use it to deliver events from one processes to another ones. If I'l release it in one process it can affect another ones, can't it?

Comment: @groaner It's supposed to. After all, you're attempting to wake processes up. Whether the process is yours or not - doesn't matter. The other processes should be able to survive being woken up without any new events added to the queue.