# Set a QML category for console.log

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm new to the Qt/QML topic and I'm trying to install a logging handler in my c++ business logic. The following code snipet installs a handler and sets a special category:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
       QLoggingCategory mainEx("main.ex");

       qCDebug(mainEx) << "debug message";
       ...
    }
```

The result is a call from the Qt backend to the following installed message handler:

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context,
                     const QString &msg)
{
   ...
}
```

In Qt 5 it is also possible to write debug messages directly in in QML with:

```
console.debug("debug message")
```

But the 'cateory' in QMessageLogConext is always 'qml'. Is it possible to set another category directly in QML?

Comment: It would nice to know why you need more categories. What you trying to achieve? You can use other members (`file, function, line`) of `QMessageLogConext` to get more context of the logging statement origin.

Comment: I want to use different QML extensions in one application and need a logging system, where I can print messages dependant from its source. For example, if a write "extension1" in categories, and a qDebug() message  is set, so this category (including the message) will appear in the customized handler. So I can use the category to find out, which extension the qDebug message produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no out of box solution available to override default category in QML engine. [Here](https://github.com/dangelog/qmllogging) is the possible solution with very good explanation and code.

Comment: Yep, that's true. There are ways of creating new categories in [Qt & C++](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/03/11/qt-weekly-1-categorized-logging/), but not in QML yet. @fischeth [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410549/how-to-redirect-qmls-console-log-to-cpp-stdout]) you have another idea.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Qt 5.8, categorized logging [available](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-loggingcategory.html) out of the box in QML.

> A logging category can be passed to console.log() and friends as the
>   first argument. If supplied to to the logger the LoggingCategory's
>   name will be used as Logging Category otherwise the default logging
>   category will be used.

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Item {
    LoggingCategory {
        id: category
        name: "com.qt.category"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
      console.log(category, "message");
    }
}
```