# Need consistent debug constants for triggering actions on all platforms

Tags: c++, linux, macos, qt, debug-symbols

I am trying to prevent showing certain error messages in Release (as stated in my question [Errors showing in Qt application - how to not display them in Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983408/errors-showing-in-qt-application-how-to-not-display-them-in-release)).

I am working on an application in Qt... on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

For Windows checking for symbols is quite simple:

```
#if defined (Q_OS_WIN32) && !defined (NDEBUG)
```

But checking for NDEBUG on Linux, with the project built using qmake, the NDEBUG is not recognized...

So I could create a constant in the pro file:

```
unix:CONFIG(release):DEFINES += NO_RELEASE_ERRORS
```

This worked for both Linux and Windows. But when I tried on mac, switching between debug and release configurations both seemed to give me the defined constant...

I have installed Qt 4.8 on the MAC but its installation may not have debug symbols...

How can I find on MAC a DEBUG and RELEASE type of symbol that can trigger or not display of errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** When testing for debug or release in `CONFIG`, use the two parameter test function `CONFIG(x,debug|release)`, where `x` is either `debug` or `release`, depending on what you wish to test for.

The `CONFIG(release)` test is wrong. You need `CONFIG(release,debug|release)`. Remember that there are multiple `debug` and `release` entries in the `CONFIG` variable (just print it out and see for yourself). It's only the *last one* that counts. That's why you should supply the second parameter to the `CONFIG` test function - it'll act only on the *last* entry to match `debug|release`, and if that entry isn't `release`, the test fails.

Comment: I think I understand this better - so if I wanted to check for "debug" with the same command I would say "CONFIG(release,debug|debug)" ?

Comment: @Thalia No. You'd say `CONFIG(debug,release|debug)`. It makes no sense to say `debug|debug`, since that's an alternative of equals and reduces to `debug`. The first argument to `CONFIG` is what you're checking for. The second argument is what `CONFIG` entries to check in - the latest of *either* of those entries is compared to the first argument and the result of the comparison is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the answer and the additional explanation and edit