# Logger class using qInstallMessageHandler can not find pointer to function?

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I have a class MyLogger which shall handle all the logging activities. Therefore I tried to use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954140/how-to-redirect-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-etc-output)

So my source is :

```
MyLogger::MyLogger(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MyLogger)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
  qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);
#else
  qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
#endif

}

#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &, const QString & str)
{
    const char * msg = str.toStdString().c_str();
#else
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
#endif
    switch (type)
    {
        case QtDebugMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug: %s\n", msg);
            break;
        case QtWarningMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %s\n", msg);
            break;
        case QtCriticalMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Critical: %s\n", msg);
            break;
        case QtFatalMsg:
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: %s\n", msg);
            abort();
    }
}
```

But then I get a:

> Error: 'myMessageOutput' was not declared in this scope
>   qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);

Answer (score 1):

Either you move `myMessageOutput()` before `MyLogger::MyLogger()`, or you use a separate declaration before that.

Comment: I moved it up! But when I call qDebug() elsewhere in my application, the old style is called???