# QNetworkAcessManager Not work in release mode on different computers

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

I have a very strange problem I create an application that use QNetworkAcessManager to download an HTML page and get the data from this page I release my application to use it on my second laptop on the same wireless connection but it not works.
on my computer, after releasing the app and use windeploy.exe to get all the dll file for this release exe I try to use it on my computer which has QT and developed on it it works fine and get the data in the file.
the problem comes when I use it on another computer the app works but when I press the button to get the data it gets nothing just empty file
so any help for this problem
this the code which I use normal QNetworkAcessManager code to get HTML page data
this code in the button to get the data

```
manager->clearAccessCache();
manager->clearConnectionCache();
if (reply != nullptr)
    delete reply;
reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://normalpage.html")));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(Finish()));
```

readyread

```
void MainWindow::readyRead()
{
    data.append(reply->readAll());
}
```

finish function I get the data of type QByteArray and use it to get the data from it the function is long
I was having this problem for about two months but I was in hurry so I used libcurl with QProcess to get this HTML page data but I now I want to know what cause this problem
**update** 
I used the code in my main.cpp to get all the Qt warnings and errors in a file as mention in the comment by Macias and I get this into the file I used append to the file so I can get all the error it comes and I got some warnings from QSslSocket if anyone can check these warnings and see if it cause the problem as I don't know

Error file

```
    Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
)
))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
```

but in the working computer I got this warrnings

```
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected ((null):0, (null))
```

**Update**
when i add the new dll files in the folder excutable file it give me this warrnings

```
    Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
```

connect the reply to the error signal

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(Error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

and the slot is here

```
    void MainWindow::Error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError Myerror)
{
    qDebug() << "QNetworkReply::NetworkError = " << Myerror;
}
```

this what i get after connect error signal and the attribute

```
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
Warning: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error ((null):0, (null))
Debug: QNetworkReply::NetworkError =  QNetworkReply::NetworkError(UnknownNetworkError) ((null):0, (null))
Debug: Attribute in finish slot =  QVariant(Invalid) ((null):0, (null))
```

when I added the three dlls file to the release folder on my computer which the app i working without them i got this error 
[image]

when i go to the path of C:\AppServ\Apache24\bin and copied this dlls (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) from this folder instead of the others i downloaded from the dll website it finally it works but what is the difference between both in the appchace folder and that are download from website?

thanks in advance

Comment: I mean curl.exe which I used to download the HTML pages

Comment: I guess that is because of SSL library(I had similar problem), but to be sure redirect your output from console to file, and check the errors (I assume that you don't have any debugger on this laptop). You have example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954140/how-to-redirect-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-etc-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have `libeay32.dll`, `libssl32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` libs in your deployment folder. If not just copy them next to your *.exe

`windeployqt` tool does not include these libs.

**EDIT:**

Your error is propably caused by incopatible version of openSSL library.
Version in use at compile time is different from this used at run-time. You can easily check it out. Add these lines after `QApplication` creation in `main.cpp`:

```
qDebug() << "SslSupport: " << QSslSocket::supportsSsl();
qDebug() << "SslLibraryBuildVersion: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
qDebug() << "SslLibraryRuntimeVersion: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
```

You should install and put to your release the most similar to build version.

Comment: I past those DLLs to my computer and it didn't work too

Comment: @noname What compiler do you use? Connect http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error-1 signal to your `reply` and print to log possible error when arrived. You should also print `QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute` from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#attribute in `finished` slot

Comment: iam using mingw

Comment: @no name What about `error` signal and `HttpStatusCodeAttribute` ?

Comment: I can't print error signal as I try this in the code but it give me an error 
QNetworkReply::NetworkError Myerror
Myerror.errorString();
in the signal of error of reply but it give me an error 
request for member 'errorString' in 'Myerror', which is of non-class type 'QNetworkReply::NetworkError'
 Myerror.errorString();

Comment: connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(Error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

void MainWindow::Error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError Myerror)
{
    qDebug() << "QNetworkReply::NetworkError = " << Myerror.errorString();
}

Comment: I add this to the question

Comment: @no name It gives you an error because `QNetworkReply::NetworkError` is enum, not class, just print it: `qDebug() << "Error: " << Myerror;`

Comment: the question updated with what I got when I use the error signal

Comment: @no name There is no HTTP response with code 0, so I'm sure that you're doing something wrong. Give some more code please (paste or better link to repo with minimal project where error occurs), because I can't reproduce your error and I see that you are not fluent with Qt programming because you making basic mistakes. If I find an issue I will explain you why etc :)

Comment: if there is an error in code i think it will not work on my computer anyway here is the code i upload it to my google drive 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5rlQZmglfhEVUlEcGxmYVdvTWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @noname Can you show your release package with all subdirectories?

Comment: thank you for your help I will take this as the solution to my question I update the question with what I did