# qt webengine redirect javascript output to GUI

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I have an application that views a page in `QWebEngineView` widget how can I redirect my javascript console log into my GUI? it currently shows in my debug output.

Comment: If you want to redirect all debug output, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954140/how-to-redirect-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-etc-output

Comment: I tried that but it seems to see only `QtDebugMsg` from my code and not the javascript console messages

Answer (score 6):

You have to subclass QWebEnginePage to override javaScriptConsoleMessage virtual function. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage)

```
class CustomPage : public QWebEnginePage
{
public:
    CustomPage(QObject* parent = 0) : QWebEnginePage(parent) {}
    virtual void javaScriptConsoleMessage(JavaScriptConsoleMessageLevel level, const QString &message, int lineNumber, const QString &sourceID)
    {
        // Here goes your logging code
    }
};
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to attach this to a `QWebEngineView`, you need to do `QWebEngineView view; CustomPage page; view.setPage(&page);`.

Comment: It is *so* annoying that they didn't just put a signal for that in the default `QWebEnginePage` implementation...