# C++: Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a log file with the following piece of code:

```
FILE* smartcutLogFile;

D1 = 0;
D2 = 0;
E2 = 0;
E3 = 0;
E4 = 0;
Z_EDGE = 0;

// save the detected values into the log file, and close it
    smartcutLogFile =  fopen ((QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() + ".txt").toStdString().c_str() ,"w+t"); // get the datetime and append .txt at the end
    std::cout<<(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss") + ".txt").toStdString().c_str()<<std::endl;
    fprintf(smartcutLogFile, "D1: %f\n D2: %f\n E2: %f\n E3: %f\n E4: %f\n Z: %f\n", D1, D2, E2, E3, E4, Z_EDGE);
    fclose(smartcutLogFile);
```

where all these doubles (E2, E3, etc.) are actually measurements from the sensors which I can see on my LineEdits, so all are OK. However the following code does not create any file or anything, it does print the file name as such:

```
2018-01-15 12.21.50.txt
```

but it does not create anything, rather prompts the following error for hundreds of times:

```
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

Where am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I get the error at the following line:

```
smartcutLogFile =  fopen ((QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() + ".txt").toStdString().c_str() ,"w+t"); // get the datetime and append .txt at the end
```

Comment: Please find out at which line of your code the "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function." error message is displayed. And also check if `smartcutLogFile` is `NULL` right after `fopen`. Be aware that `fopen` can fail.

Comment: Could it be something related to admin rights? I am trying to create the file under a folder which is under C: directly.

Comment: @Schütze: You tagged the language as C++ but the APIs you are using is of C. And, you are using Qt too! Why don't you simply use `QFile` to do this? You won't be doing those conversions from `QString` to `std::string` or C-strings.

Comment: Yes it could. Does `fopen` return `NULL`? Are you able to create a file in that location manually with the explorer? Try putting your file into another location. If `fopen` returns `NULL` what does `errno` contain? Read the `fopen` documentation.

Comment: @Azeem I also have qt tag along with C++ under the question. And you are more than welcome to offer an alternative if that is going to solve the question.

Comment: @Schütze: In addition to my previous comment, you could do this using Qt logging features. Take a look at `qInstallMsgHandler()`. Here's an example from SO's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954188/7670262).

Comment: what is the filename that you pass to fopen function. I can see you don't use format string here, and you use format string when you print filename. So maybe filename is different.

Comment: @Schütze: Right. That's why I asked to determine whether using C APIs is a compulsion for you. If you are good to go with Qt then you must. It'll make your life easier! ;)

Comment: @Sandro Forget the printing part since that is not the part prompting the error.  The filename is the current datetime in `char*[]` form after the conversions, the error comes from `fopen()` function. Somewhere in that line the error lies.

Comment: @Schütze Yes error comes from fopen function Maybe the reason is invalid filename. That is why I ask you to check that result of  your date/time conversion is correct and gives the valid filename.

Comment: @Sandro You were actually right. The formatting was missing. Add your answer and I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an error occurs during the conversion of date/time to string.
The result of conversion gives you invalid filename and it can be the reason of fopen function failure.

This should work:

```
(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd h.mm.ss") + ".txt").toStdString()).c_str()
```