# Qt error messages when running Qt5 application

Tags: qt, qt5

I have written a Qt GUI application using Qt5 on Fedora 29.  The application, which uses all kinds of Qt widgets, works as intended, but when I run it from the command line, I'm inundated with errors (like the one below) on the console:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 4225, resource id: 36071117, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
```

For example, if I have a simple QMessageBox, with a simple text message and one "OK" push button, clicking on that OK push button will close the message box (as expected) and ALWAYS print out the error above.

```
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Title", "Fatal Error");
}
```

When I google these errors, I see people saying that these messages are harmless and that they can be safely ignored, but I find it hard to believe that Qt would make the effort of printing these messages if nothing is wrong.

Does anyone know what these messages mean and what I can do to get rid of them?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question, as Nikos C. has commented above, this is a bug in Qt.

You can always suppress diagnostic output of Qt. That has been answered some years ago: [How to redirect qDebug, qWarning, qCritical etc output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954140/how-to-redirect-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-etc-output)

There are a few exceptional messages that can't be suppressed (e. g. [qSetGlobalQHashSeed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#qSetGlobalQHashSeed) uses printf for warnings), but these are very rare.