# QtConcurrent::run() for a member function does not use the original instance

Tags: qt, qtconcurrent

I want to use `QtConcurrent::run()` for a member function, but it seems that it doesn't use the pointer to the instance. Instead, it looks like the default constructor is called

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent>

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Foo(int n = 0):n(n){}
    Foo(const Foo & f):Foo(f.n){}

    void foo(){qDebug() << "Foo " << n;}
    void bar(){QtConcurrent::run(this, &Foo::foo);}

private:
    int n;
};

void test(){
  Foo foo = Foo(2);
  foo.foo();
  foo.bar();
  QtConcurrent::run(&foo, &Foo::foo);
  QtConcurrent::run(&foo, &Foo::bar);
}
```

And the results of running `test()` are :

```
Foo  2
Foo  0 // Should be a 2
Foo  0 // Should be a 2
Foo  0 // Should be a 2
```

---

Edit : My instance indeed went out of scope. This code works fine

```
void test(){
    Foo * foo = new Foo(2);
    foo->foo();
    foo->bar();
    QtConcurrent::run(foo, &Foo::foo);
    QtConcurrent::run(foo, &Foo::bar);
}
```

Comment: btw why is `foo` subclass of `QObject`?

Comment: `qDebug()` is NOT thread-safe. You must not use it from different threads.

Comment: @UmNyobe because my class in my real problem inherits from QObject

Comment: @SaZ Are you sure about that? I don't think you're right.

Comment: "does not use the original instance" ... because that instance isn't there anymore

Comment: @KubaOber http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#details - this class is not thread-safe or reentrant. And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527253/is-qdebug-thread-safe

Comment: @SaZ The class doesn't have to be thread-safe nor reentrant, because you are not passing it anywhere. `qDebug()` gives you a fresh instance of the message logger, each and every time. It is perfectly fine to use such separate instances in multiple threads, in parallel. It is not defined whether such use introduces a synchronization point, so certainly you might want to assume that worst case there's a lock that `qDebug()` acquires. This is probably a pessimistic assumption, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a call to an object which has been destructed is undefined behavior. What is happening is that when `QtConcurrent::run` effectively execute `Foo::bar`, the parameter `foo` has been destructed.

If I try to replicate your code I have:

```
Foo  2 
Foo  1730312062 
Foo  1730312062
```

Issue come from the fact that the object `foo` is on the stack and will be invalid as soon as `test` return. **Provide a greater lifetime to your object.**